# My nested loop is printing one row less than wanted/expected

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I need to prompt user to pick h and use h to print out that much number of rows where each row is incremented by 1. So I do understand this part and I have nested my loops but when I pick exmp: h=4 it prints 3 rows. I am beginner in programming and been breaking my head over this for some days now :P

I prefer you to give me some tips how to solve this by myself not only to get the anwser. 
thank you!

```
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
          for( int j = 0; j < i; j++)
          {
              printf("#");
          }
     printf("\n");
}
   }
```

Comment: Consider using a debugger, you will see the problem right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first loop iteration `i` and `j` will both take the value 0. The second loop won't be entered because `j<i` is false.

In the last iteration, `i` will take the value h-1 and `j` will iterate from 0 to h-2, thus printing h-1 #s.

Consider changing the first loop to the following :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= h; i++)
```

Comment: I am glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop iterates exactly `h` times.

However for the first iteration when `i` is equal to `0` the inner loop is skipped because the condition of the loop

```
for( int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                ^^^^^
```

evaluates to false.

It seems what you mean is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): " );

        unsigned int h;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &h ) != 1 || h == 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < h; i++ )
        {
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
            {
                printf( "#" );
            }
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the program output might look like

```
Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 10

#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########
#########
##########

Enter the height of a pyramid (0 - exit): 0
```